# Hide "Add Resources" from week view in SharePoint 2013 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have written below code to hide the "Add resource" and "Remove" image from the group view calendar in SharePoint 2013.

```
function HideResources() {

jQuery(".ms-acal-entity-res ").hide();
jQuery(".ms-acal-remove").hide();
jQuery(".ms-acal-apanel-title").hide();
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideResources");
```

It hides the desired image when page loaded.
But when i click on previous /next button,its not hiding all these.

Waiting for your response.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint loads the calendar items dynamically, that means for every async refresh (change weeks/months etc) you need to call your script-method again.

Otherwise your view will be 'reset'.